# Ruby: How to pass data to a program running in background

Tags: ruby, input, background-process

Although Ruby is my language of choice right now, I don't mind so much if anyone answers this with examples in another language, as I am more interested in the concept.

**If I have a script running In the background; how would I program that script so that I could pass data input to it whilst it is still running?**

If I were running it in a terminal In the foreground, the solution would be as simple as creating a Thread, and killing that Thread upon STDIN at which point a seperate function would invoke to handle the User Input.
However considering that this script is running in the background, that method is not practical. I assume that arguments are the best way to interface with the program (although I could be wrong on that).

Of course there are plenty of methods to pass data to the background program, such as linking it to a file, which I then write data too and the program then reads. **However I want this data to be inputted strictly through the terminal**.

**To elaborate:** There is an Operating System process which is perpetually running in the background, however I can pass data to it to alter its function by running a command such as: `program_name -newdata`, and I am trying to program the same functionality into one of my own scripts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use message passing by using unix sockets. You can do it in one [executable](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/how-to-make-a-ruby-file-executable/) file, but for simplicity I do it in 2 separate.

In the `program_name_background` file you can kick of a UNIXServer that is listening for unix sockets and parsing messages (and run whatever you need in a different thread):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'socket'
require 'json'
require 'FileUtils'

socket_path = "/tmp/program_name_background.sock"

at_exit { FileUtils.rm socket_path }

server = UNIXServer.new socket_path

loop do
  client = server.accept
  message = client.read
  json_message = JSON.parse message, symbolize_names: true
  p json_message

  break if json_message[:type] == "SIGTERM"
end
```

In the `program_name_control` file you can read attributes from the command line and send message to the background process:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'socket'
require 'json'

case ARGV[0]
when "-newdata"
  message = {
    type: :newdata,
    data: ARGV[1]
  }
when "stop"
  message = { type: :SIGTERM }
else
  p "Error: unknown param: #{ARGV[0]}"
  exit
end

client = UNIXSocket.open "/tmp/program_name_background.sock"
client.print JSON.generate(message)
client.close
```

For parsing options you can use the built-in [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html)

You can test it like:

- Start the background process: `./program_name_background`
- Send a message from a different tab: `./program_name_control -newdata 118`

You can also set up symlinks to those files from the `/usr/local/bin` folder so you can call them from anywhere without the leading `./`

You can daemonizing the background process so it wont be attached to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this kind of behavior. Assuming you want something simple, you can try these solutions :

You can pass data throught a file, define specific access rights to this file and rely on your OS.

You can also implement an authenticated service and bind this service on a local socket.

Comment: I know this is very old, but I want to point out that you don't want to use a file, especially when you update that data constantly. Doing so can cause empty results in between writes, giving annoying edge-cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind but it is possible to reliably communicate with files. Of course it is easy to design something that won't work, whatever the communication tool you choose.

Comment: I'm sure we're thinking similarly. It's easy for anyone to take this idea and implement it to completely rewrite the file on every update, where the secondary process will intermittently catch the file on an update before the write, causing an empty result. Sure, you can write logic to keep this from happening, but most people writing it based on this suggestion, probably won't have a lot of experience with the File library (or they would have come up with this idea organically). My point is that people can expect more issues, compared to a socket server handling state (imo).